# I can't test jsonobject with "is" in JsonDataObject

Tags: json, windows, rest, parsing, delphi

Delphi 11.2, Windows 10 x64

I'm using JsonDataObject from https://github.com/ahausladen/JsonDataObjects

I don't understand why I can't test an object to know if it's a `TJsonArray` or `TJsonObject` like this:

```pascal
if (arrayValue[0].ObjectValue is TJsonArray) or (arrayValue[0].ObjectValue is TJsonObject) then
```

Comment: Hard to tell from one line of code. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectValue` is always a `TJsonObject`, it can never be a `TJsonArray`. Just as `ArrayValue` is always a `TJsonArray`, it can never be a `TJsonObject`.

To know what type an array element is, use its `Typ` property instead:

```
if (arrayValue[0].Typ = jdtArray) or (arrayValue[0].Typ = jdtObject) then
```